# Overlaying 2 images at the same time using scale2ref

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to merge these 2 commands into one command, is it possible ?

```
ffmpeg -i Overlay.png -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -filter_complex "scale2ref[a][b];[b][a]overlay" -y output.png
```

and :

```
ffmpeg -i Overlay2 -i output.png  -filter_complex "scale2ref[a][b];[b][a]overlay" -y final-out-put.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple scale2ref and overlay filters, like below.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i Overlay.png -i Overlay2 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i1][v];[2][v]scale2ref[i2][v];[v][i1]overlay[v];[v][i2]overlay" -vframes 1 -y final-out-put.png`